# displaying array values in textbox

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio

Is it possible to display arrays in a textbox?

I'm working on a ASP.NET calculator for class, the users will click on a button which will store the number in an array and display it in the text box.

This is what I have so far but it keeps giving me an error

```
    ArrayNum.Add("1") ' Storing value in the Array List
    DisplayTextBox.Text += ArrayNum(1)
```

I want to read whatever the user inputs as a String and then have the calculator evaluate it mathematically

Comment: its not obvious why you are using an arraylist here, how many textboxes you have there?

Comment: I only have one textbox. It's like a regular calculator with buttons for each number. The professor wants us to use arrays and then parse it into an equation so the program can calculate it

Comment: in which event are you adding the numbers? can you show the code of the event

Comment: I haven't wrote the code for the equations. I'm still trying to get the numbers to show up in the textbox as users are clicking each button. Which is why I asked if its possible to display String arrays in the textbox

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the last number you added to ArrayNum :

```
ArrayNum.Add("1")
DisplayTextBox.Text &= ArrayNum(ArrayNum.Count - 1)
```

Comment: I that's what I had at first. But I think we're suppose to store it in an array first. So is there a way to display the stored value?

Comment: I have a question about the "ArrayNum.Count - 1". Let's say the 1 is stored in the second array spot, would it just be ArrayNum(1) like how I had it?

Comment: But then it gives me an error saying "Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.Parameter name: index"

Comment: @toilabav90 because the first time you are adding 1 to the array, there was no number at index 1

Comment: So then how would I be able to add 1 to the index 1? Because I was able to add 0 to index 0. If I use ArrayNum.Count - 1 it'll replace whatever is in index 0, right?

Comment: `ArrayNum.Count - 1` is not replacing, it just gets you the value stored at the last index, so what are you trying to accomplish? you want to show all the values stored in the ArrayNum?\

Comment: Ah I think my logic was wrong. Okay so let's say after the user clicks the first number that'll be stored in index 0. After that, the user will need to click an operator (or another a second number), which has to be stored in index 1, correct? So how would I be able to store (and show) what the user clicks on after the first number?

Comment: I'm setting ArrayNum As New ArrayList so I want to be able to add to the array as the user clicks on each button

Comment: Oh okay I tried using ArrayNum.Count -1 and was able to display "1" when the button 1 was clicked. I guess I thought that would show me the value of index 0. Can you explain this to me? In your answer above, is that one stored in index 1? because I need it to

Comment: @toilabav90 my question is, are you handling different button click events for each button?

Comment: Yes. sorry for misunderstanding you

Comment: @toilabav90 I suggest you consider having them in one event handler. so you don't need to repeat the code for each event.

Comment: But how do I add number 1 to index 1 of the array after adding number 0 to index 0? because like I said, it's giving me an error

Comment: @toilabav90 put `ArrayNum.Add("0")` then `ArrayNum.Add("1")`

Comment: that's what I had but like I said it was giving me an error. Anyways I got confirmation from the professor, it seemed I had my logic wrong. But I would still like to know why I got the error despite having ArrayNum.Add("1"). Look at my code at the first post, it's exactly what you said but I got the error....

Comment: @toilabav90 I'm sorry if my answer didn't help. Its just I wouldn't understand the problem if I don't see your code.

Answer (score 0):

You got the error because arrays start from POSITION 0 and so the statement...

```
ArrayNum.Count - 1
```

is effectively the POSITION of the TOTAL count of elements in the array.

And the reason you got the error is because...
When your code states...

```
ArrayNum.Add("1") ' Storing value in the Array List
```

What your are doing is adding the value 1 to the object ArrayNum

And where your code says....

```
DisplayTextBox.Text += ArrayNum(1)
```

What you are attempting to do is to display the element at position(1) which in REALITY is the SECOND element because arrays start at ZERO.

IF your code said...

```
DisplayTextBox.Text += ArrayNum(0)
```

Then your error would go away.

Comment: Additionally if you simply want to DISPLAY the array data or content, then it is sufficient to use DisplayTextBox.Text = ArrayNum(0) to display the FIRST element in the array and DisplayTextBox.Text = ArrayNum(1) for the second element and DisplayTextBox.Text = ArrayNum(2) for the third element and so on